# how should I render views when users habtm roles. cake

Tags: authentication, cakephp, rendering, roles

ok here is my issue...

user habtm groups(roles)

i have views for admins, boardmembers, managers, and vps.

so when an user have just one role the app reads the role and we're going fine... BUT when he/she/it have two or more roles it just take the first one and dissmiss the others...

***the questions***

- how should i manage those role so the
  user can choose what view to see?
- should i tell the user what role he
  wants to play after login? Ex: made him decide (want's to play admin, want's to play manager, etc)
- is there a way the user can play two
  roles at the same time at one
  session? Ex: I have two roles (vps, manager). render two views in one?
- or should i choose a view for that
  role that have more privilege? Ex: I have two roles (admin, manager) so i use admin views not the manager's ones.

a lot of questions... so start answering hahaha 
thanks guys...

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to answer because the sort of questions you're asking require us to decide how your application will work. You have to do that yourself and make appropriate design & programming based on your decision.

As for *display* of HABTM records, I usually use checkboxes or some graphical readonly equivalent.

My suggestion is that you look around the web to see how it works on other sites - social sites like Flickr and Facebook are a good hunting ground as they have lots of groups, categories etc.

Comment: ok thanks Leo... BUT if you were the programer... how would you do it? thats what i want to know...

Comment: i think that i need 4 "backends", one for each role... but the main question is how to manage users with two roles

Comment: Without knowing what it is you wish to achieve, I can't offer an answer. If you are clear in your own mind what you want, then that is what you program for.

Answer (score 0):

user admin routing... and have many prefixes. and may be in the place where you display user information. you can also list the other roles he can play.