# manage users views with different roles cakephp

Tags: cakephp, authentication, view, rendering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how should I render views when users habtm roles. cake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054182/how-should-i-render-views-when-users-habtm-roles-cake)

hi i got users habtm roles 
the thing is when i login i dont know how to separate or mix the views for users that have more than one role...

any help?

how would you manage this issue? by letting the user select which role he wants to play? or mixing the views?

dont be cocky... express yourself!

Comment: need more info. dont understand the problem. can u give a use case.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a seperate directory for each level of user.

Use the following command to set the view path

```
    $this->viewPath = 'users' . DS. $privLevel
```

so then you can make a have a different copy of your view files in each of a bunch of directories

```
/users/1/view.ctp
/users/2/view.ctp
/users/3/view.ctp
/users/4/view.ctp
...
```